# Does Visual Studio 2019 docker honor the launchSettings.json environmentVariables

Tags: visual-studio-2019, docker-for-windows

Does VS2019 honor the launchsettings.json "environmentVariables?

```json
    "Docker": {
      "commandName": "Docker",
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "launchUrl": "{Scheme}://{ServiceHost}:{ServicePort}",
      "environmentVariables": {
        "Business__ApiUrl": "https://localhost:5113",
        "Business__BusinessUrl": "https://localhost:5123",
        "ASPNETCORE_URLS": "https://+:5123;http://+:5120",
        "ASPNETCORE_HTTPS_PORT": "5123 ",
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
      },
      "publishAllPorts": true,
      "httpPort": 5120,
      "useSSL": true,
      "sslPort": 5123
    }
```

I don't see Business__ApiUrl used in the Visual Studio's docker run or in the container.  VS also disregards the ASPNETCORE_URLS, or ASPNETCORE_HTTPS_PORT.

Here's the command VS executes (copied from the logs)

```sh
1> docker run -dt -v "C:\Users\me\vsdbg\vs2017u5:/remote_debugger:rw" -v "D:\dev\3ta\src\3ta.business:/app" -v "D:\dev\3ta\src:/src/" -v "C:\Users\me\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\UserSecrets:/root/.microsoft/usersecrets:ro" -v "C:\Users\me\AppData\Roaming\ASP.NET\Https:/root/.aspnet/https:ro" -v "C:\Users\me\.nuget\packages\:/root/.nuget/fallbackpackages3" -v "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\Shared\NuGetPackages:/root/.nuget/fallbackpackages" -v "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft\Xamarin\NuGet\:/root/.nuget/fallbackpackages2" -e "DOTNET_USE_POLLING_FILE_WATCHER=1" -e "ASPNETCORE_LOGGING__CONSOLE__DISABLECOLORS=true" -e "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Development" -e "NUGET_PACKAGES=/root/.nuget/fallbackpackages3" -e "NUGET_FALLBACK_PACKAGES=/root/.nuget/fallbackpackages;/root/.nuget/fallbackpackages2;/root/.nuget/fallbackpackages3" -p 5120:5120 -p 5123:5123 -P --name 3ta.business --entrypoint tail image3tabusiness:dev -f /dev/null
1>  29016d3f14e56b0bda7d63723a8ccff3030c1ee061b8357839e320d4eb635f0a
```

I don't mind using an alternative way of passing settings, I just don't want to rule out a method by mistake.

Frustrating not knowing why something fails.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately it seems it does not. It is a bit of a hack, but one way to get around this is by passing environment variables using `DockerfileRunArguments` as shown below in launchSettings.json, making sure to use backslashes to escape the extra double quotation marks:

```json
    "Docker": {
      "commandName": "Docker",
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "launchUrl": "{Scheme}://{ServiceHost}:{ServicePort}",
      "publishAllPorts": true,
      "httpPort": 5120,
      "useSSL": true,
      "sslPort": 5123,
      "DockerfileRunArguments": "-e \"Business__ApiUrl=https://localhost:5113\""
    }
```

This appends the arguments to the `docker run` command:
[image]

The passed environment variables can then be seen in the container:
[image]